# Show() Function Not Activating When Value Reaches 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, if-statement, show-hide

So I'm trying to have a submit button show once a progress bar reaches 100%. The value of the progress bar increases when each of two drop-downs are selected, and subsequent check-boxes are chosen. Here's the div for the bar and button:

```
<div id="submitContainer" align="center">

<br />
<progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100"><div class="progressbar"></div></progress>
<br />
<input id="submitButton" type="button" value="Check Trade" onclick="function()" />    
</div>
```

Here's the script to increase the value of the progress bar:

```
var doneA = false;
    $('#teamASelect').on('change', function() {
        if (!doneA) {
        $("#progressBar").attr('value', $("#progressBar").prop('value')+25);
        doneA = true;
    }
}); 

var doneB = false;
    $('#teamBSelect').on('change', function() {
        if (!doneB) {
        $("#progressBar").attr('value', $("#progressBar").prop('value')+25);
        doneB = true;
    }
});

var doneC = false;
    $('.checkA').on('change', function() {
        if (!doneC) {
        $("#progressBar").attr('value', $("#progressBar").prop('value')+25);
        doneC = true;
    }
});

var doneD = false;
    $('.checkB').on('change', function() {
        if (!doneD) {
        $("#progressBar").attr('value', $("#progressBar").prop('value')+25);
        doneC = true;
    }
}); 

var progress = $("#progressBar").attr('value');
```

and here's the script that should show the submit button...or so I thought:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#submitButton').hide();
});

$('#progressBar').prop('value').on('change', function () {
    if (progress > 99) {
    $('#submitButton').show();
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: `.value` properties typically are strings, not numbers… Have you looked at all at what values you are actually getting?

Comment: I set up an alert to show what the value of the progress bar is on change. When I load the page it pops up a 0, but nothing happens on selecting a drop down or checking a box, so I'm guessing the issue has to be with how I'm setting up my on change functions. Though, that seems strange because the progress bar reacts visually by filling up as I select the drop-down and check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code is wrong

```
$('#progressBar').prop('value').on('change', function () {
```

`.prop(xxx)` will return the value of that property.

You need to drop the .prop()

```
$('#progressBar').on('change', function () {
```

Now what is `progress` in `if (progress > 99) {` ? Shouldn't you be reading the value?

```
if (this.value > 99) {
```

---

```
$('#progressBar').on('change', function () {
    if (this.value > 99) {
    $('#submitButton').show();
    }
});
```

and setting the value in JS does not trigger change so you need to trigger it

```
$("#progressBar").attr('value', $("#progressBar").prop('value')+25).trigger("change");
```

Comment: Got rid of the .prop('value'), but it doesn't fix the issue. And progress is a variable that's supposed to contain the value of the progress bar:

var progress = $("#progressBar").attr('value');

Comment: Ah, setting the value does not trigger change, you need to trigger it.